# Swift NSCache struct not saved properly

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to cache a Struct, this is my code :

```
class UserManager {
   static let sharedInstance : UserManager = UserManager()
   fileprivate let cacheKey = "currentUser" as AnyObject
   var currentUser: User? {
      didSet {
         self.cacheUser()
      }
   }

  fileprivate func getUserFromCache() -> User?{
     let cache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
       // here the user is always nil
     if let user = cache.object(forKey: cacheKey) as? User {
            return user
      }
      else { 
        return nil 
     }
  }

  fileprivate func cacheUser() {
     let cache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
     if let user = currentUser{
         cache.setObject(user  as AnyObject, forKey: cacheKey)
     }
     //Here : print user work fine and user is not nil
     print(cache.object(forKey: cacheKey) as? User)
  }

   init() {
      currentUser = getUserFromCache()
   }
}
```

The problem is that when the function `getUserFromCache()` return always nil even after executing `cacheUser` function.

What's wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new cache every time the cacheUser and getUser functions are called, you want to have one cache not lots of them. Put this after the sharedInstance at the top:

```
var cache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
```

and delete the let cache = ... from the cacheUser and getUser functions.

Comment: This solve part of my problem but now when I restart the app the cash is empty, I want to save the cache so next time when app lunched he get the user from cache.

Comment: Saving and loading is a different question, but there are many tutorials on the internet and answers on Stack Overflow about saving data in swift. Please have a go at it and post another question if you have problems.

Comment: NSUserDefaults might be the easiest for what you are doing. If you need to store more information later you might want to look at NSCoding or CoreData but they are harder to use.